# pandas append column from dataframe to a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, named-entity-recognition

i have a dataframe as below

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa |
| 2 | bbbb |

i read the above to a dataframe and i need to convert the text column to a list for perform NER extraction

```
tags = []
for i in df['text'].tolis(():
  tdoc = nlp(i)
  for tags in tdoc.ents:
   tags.append((df.id,tags.text,tags.label_))
```

Above works and i get the NER tags which i would like to export to dataframe along with the 'id' column from the dataframe

```
df_tag = pd.DataFrame_from_records(tags, columns = ['id', 'name', 'type'])
```

The problem here is my id columns repeats as below

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 2 | NER A | Type A |
| 1 2 | NER B | Type B |

Desired output

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NER A | Type A |
| 2 | NER B | Type B |

Comment: If you put `print(df.id)` inside your second `for` loop the printed values might make it clearer why you have the problem with `id` in your `df_tag`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that `df.id` returns a Series, from which you are repeatedly appending the index, not the values.

Also, lines 4 and 5, it should be `tag`, not `tags`.

Try like this:

```py
tags = []
for i in df['text'].tolist():
    tdoc = nlp(i)
    for tag in tdoc.ents:
        tags.append((df.id.values,tag.text,tag.label_))
```